# procedure creation issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure that will list out all contents of a table but oracle tells me that the procedure has compilation errors. I am running on SQL plus. Any ideas?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure payrollproc
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM payroll;
END;
```

Comment: SHOW ERR will show the line and column of the error.  Plus your code, as is,  does not do anything.  Is this some kind of a first, do-nothing pass on writing code just to see how things work?  Do you have a / in the left column on the last row of your code?

Comment: yes , this code is just to display all the contents of the table. also , a / will be inserted after end;

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of
the following:
( ; is with authid as cluster compress order using compiled
wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable pipelined
result_cache
The symbol "is" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.

Comment: Well - as is, you cannot ever see the output.  Procedures by themselves, and as you wrote this one, do not do output to the screen or to a file.  You call DBMS_OUTPUT to write to a terminal.  When ther is one.  Which will not work in a procedure.  Procedures run over in the database as a separate process from sqlplus with no terminal. So it cannot write to the terminal.  UTL_FILE will write a file but the files go to a special directory on the same machine as the oracle instance runs on, Not your home directory. Seeing file output  can be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure payrollproc as
BEGIN
   for c_rec in ( SELECT * FROM payroll)
   Loop
       dbms_output.put_line(c_rec.col1 || '  ' || c_rec.col2 || ' ' || ......);
   End loop;
END;
/
```

But, I would suggest just run the select statement, a stored proc is too much work for such a basic function.

Comment: you are indeed right , it is too much work as you are using a cursor to iterate through the rows

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in the error message: You're missing a keyword before BEGIN.  If you were to put the word IS before BEGIN, it will compile.  See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php) for more details.  Also, you will need a cursor to view the details.  Best of luck.

Comment: It won't as the OP isn't putting the results of the select statement into a variable.